# Oracle SQL Trigger - Update on date

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have two tables:

Assessment and Assessment_Announcement

```
CREATE TABLE  "ASSESSMENT" 
  (     "ASSESSMENT_NAME" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "DEADLINE_DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        CONSTRAINT "ASSESSMENT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ASSESSMENT_NAME") ENABLE
  )

CREATE TABLE  "ASSESSMENT_ANNOUNCEMENT" 
   (    "ASSESSMENT_NAME" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "DEADLINE_DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "ATTENTION" VARCHAR2(500) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
  CONSTRAINT "ASSESSMENT_ANNOUNCEMENT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ASSESSMENT_NAME")  ENABLE
   )
```

I am looking at implementing a trigger which updates to the 'ASSESSMENT_ANNOUNCEMENT' table when the date in the DEADLINE_DATE column on the ASSESSMENT table is within 7 days. The data might have been stored for 14 days, but when it is within 7 days of the deadline - it triggers. This shouldn't trigger on insert unless the insert date is within 7 days of the deadline.

So far I have the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "TEST" 
AFTER INSERT ON ASSESSMENT
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
insert into ASSESSMENT_ANNOUNCEMENT(ASSESSMENT_NAME, DEADLINE_DATE, ATTENTION)
values (:new.ASSESSMENT_NAME, :new.DEADLINE_DATE, 'DEADLINE IS 7 DAYS OR LESS');
WHERE DEADLINE_DATE >= (SYSDATE) - 7
```

Any help and guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What would be the problem with your existing code?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want

```
BEGIN
  IF :new.deadline_date >= sysdate + 7
  THEN
    INSERT INTO assessment_announcement( assessment_name, deadline_date, attention )
      VALUES( :new.assessment_name, :new.deadline_date, 'Deadline is 7 days or less' );
  END IF;
END;
```

Note that an Oracle `DATE` always contains a day component and a time component.  So `sysdate + 7` returns exactly 24*7 = 168 hours ago.  If it is currently 4:00 PM on Feb 26, it would return 4:00 PM on March 5.  If you want the trigger to insert a row in `assessment_announcement` if the `deadline_date` is any time on March 5, you'd need `trunc(sysdate) + 7`.

Comment: Hi guys! The help so far is great and I'm looking to have a go at getting some code to work! :) One point - If the assessment deadline has been entered one month ago and turns into it needing to trigger an update because the date has turned into it being due in 7 days - this isn't a true trigger is it? Because the user isn't inserting 7 days from the deadline - But I'm still looking to to trigger? I can't see any other way of updating across. Sorry for any confusion. And thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can accomplish what you want with a trigger as you have no guarantee that the table will be updated within the timeframe you want.  Instead you should be looking to run a stored procedure to do this that can be scheduled on an appropriate interval; say every day or every 12 hours.  I've done this with MSSQL and not oracle, but this [article](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/scheduler-10g.php) should help you get started on your way.

The PL-SQL BLock you want to schedule is your query above.  You could modify it to be

```
insert into ASSESSMENT_ANNOUNCEMENT(ASSESSMENT_NAME, DEADLINE_DATE, ATTENTION)
Select ASSESSMENT_NAME, DEADLINE_DATE, 'Deadline is 7 days or less'
FROM ASSESSMENT
WHERE DEADLINE_DATE >= (SYSDATE) - 7
```